# How to enable the geographical location of the image seen for the lock screen in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, geolocation, lock-screen

I upgraded my laptop system from Windows 8 to Windows 10, I can see different lock screens, but my friend who upgraded her system from Windows 7 to Windows 10 can see the geographical location of different scenes which change automatically every day.

I want to see the geographical location of the scene too.

I searched in the settings but could not find it. How can I find and adjust this setting?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

I have just found an option on the settings for the lock screen to enable tips and extra information. I don't know if this will give you the information you expect as I have it disabled on my machine.

[image: Enable extra information on the Windows 10 lock screen]

---

**Original Answer**
I suspect your friend has got an extra app to retrieve the geographic location of the images. I haven't been able to find anything that gives this information by default.

All is not lost though. There is a way you can find the information you ask for. Although you have to do a bit of digging.

The images are distributed through Microsoft's Content Delivery Network and are stored on your PC in the following location:

```
C:\Users\YOURNAMEHERE\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets
```

You might have to enable "show hidden files" in order to get to this location. In this folder there are a lot of files with random names like:

```
b8ec8fee2e928bbcd541544a9762c1165c64526aff766b666b9408eaae8774b7
```

If you add `.jpg` to the end of this file name you will discover that it turns into a picture file. You can now open the file properties window and view the metadata. Sometimes this metadata will include GPS co-ordinates, in others (like my example) it will have a completed description and tags.

[image: Windows Lock screen example]

Comment: i followed the path you mentioned and i can see the metadata of the image. but the option to get the fun facts and more information is not available in my setting, how to make that available? also, i checked her setting, there was no such option for fun facts, in fact her setting was same as mine. can you please tell me how to enable this fun facts and more info option in lock screen settings?

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you using? Is your computer on a company network?

Comment: yes, i am using computer on computer network. i found this link, may be its because of pro version of windows 10:https://www.maketecheasier.com/customize-lock-screen-windows-10/

Comment: I am on Win10 Pro. The option might have been disabled by your IT department, have a chat with them.

Comment: but my friend is also using same company network and she also upgraded from win7 to win10. then is it possible that though we use same network, this can happen?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem but in a different way. Maybe that would help you, too.

Go to Personalization settings. Turn Off the "Show lockscreen background picture on sign-in screen" option. While this button is on, your password dialog box will have the same lockscreen background. This locks all the fun facts and location info for the background.

If you turn it off, you can see the fun facts and your password dialog box will have a plain blue background now. Refer image for more info.

[image: Screenshot of Lockscreen tab in Personalization settings]

Hope this helps.